# Allowing identity insert on temp table produces an error

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

We have a strange issue where setting identity insert to on on a temp-table throws an error.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: IDENTITY_INSERT ist für die "tempdb.dbo.#**temp490**____________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000083"-Tabelle bereits auf ON festgelegt. Der SET-Vorgang für die #**temp561**-Tabelle kann nicht ausgeführt werden.

The weird part in this exception is the two different table names.

This only occurs ocassionaly and we have no indication what is causing it.
It appears in a multi threaded environment, where each thread creates a temp table using a

> select top 0 * into #tmpXXX from someTable

Here is the version of SqlServer

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64) 
>       Apr 29 2016 23:23:58 
>       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>       Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 6.3  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Is this a bug?

Comment: See duplicate: _"At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON."_

Comment: Couldnt find it cause of my translation. Thank you.